# Improving Datatable performance symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, datatable

I'm new to symfony and i'm not able to find a solution for my problem. Actually, i'm working with datatable to load about 5000records with symfony 3, doctrine ORM. the problem is page load takes a lot of time sometimes more than 1 minute.

I've found solutions such as including pagination, i've used this plugin
Pagination : https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle
but it doesn't fit my actual need. i've also tested this bundle 
DATATABLE : https://github.com/waldo2188/DatatableBundle#rendering-inside-twig, it doesn't give me the hand to personalize the template, because for the moment i'm doing a lot of conditions on my twig template that i can't do directly on jquery and that's why i need to find a way to load data with ajax but keep my own twig template.

Can you please help??

Comment: You don't need a plugin for pagination, something simple as keeping track of the offset by a GET parameter would suffice. And then you're able to style the table as you like.

Comment: Use the ajax options for datatables

Comment: i've used ajax options but like i said before, it will populate only rows with data, when i actually need to keep my twig template

Comment: niels i don't understand what you mean

Comment: What @Niels is saying is that you could have something like `/yourUrl/{pageNumber}` and just do your query with an offset and a limit

Comment: I think you have different problem here. Your records probably have relations with other entities/entity and you are trying to access these other entities from twig. 

Could be the case? I had problem like this and I solved it by joining information, so no additional SQL requests are being called.

Comment: I have a feeling you're not explicitly joining relations in your entities, causing SQL to do potentially 5000 * (# of relations) extra queries, rather than 1 single query.  Use the Profiler to see how many queries are being run on a particular page.

Comment: the data i select is only from one specific table, i did use the profiler and i think that there are only two queries that are executed, the first one is for user authentication and second the one that selects data for datatable

Comment: @JasonRoman That's exactly my thoughts. I had problems like these, when i had no experience with Doctrine.